# convert neagative out put signal of sensor to apply adc

Tags: microcontroller, sensor, adc

I have a problem in convert out of RPM sensor that has -10v - +10v analog output signal.
How can I convert the output signal to 0-5v by practical circuit to apply in ADC of micro?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I measure a negative voltage with a ADC?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/3105/how-do-i-measure-a-negative-voltage-with-a-adc)

Comment: literally dozens to hundreds other answers if you search here.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I think this question had been asked before, but the one listed does not match the voltage ranges requested

Comment: @VoltageSpike that is indeed the case, but the approaches shown in the answers do translate (haha, pun) to these voltages, too.

Comment: The op might not be able to translate

Comment: What rpm sensor is this? Part number? It outputs -10V to +10V?

Comment: @VoltageSpike if that's the case, they're welcome to ask how to transfer that knowledge, but honestly, voltage dividers, inverting amplifiers and opamp constant voltage adders: all topics covered here before, in breadth.